# Search nested object and return whole path

Tags: javascript, json, object, underscore.js, lodash

I have below JavaScript with n level children and want to search for id and if any of item from has matching id than need to return object from root to matching item.

I want to return entire hierarchy of found item from root till object with it's children.

I tried with lodash and underscore and could not find easy solution.

```js
input: {
  "children": [{
      "name": "Home",
      "title": "Home",
      "id": "home1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC",
      "title": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC",
      "id": "BAR1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Global Businesses",
        "title": "Global Businesses",
        "id": "GB1",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Commercial Banking",
          "title": "Commercial Banking",
          "id": "CB1",
          "children": [{
            "name": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES",
            "title": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES",
            "id": "FG1",
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "RISK MANAGEMENT",
      "title": "RISK MANAGEMENT",
      "id": "RM1",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}

Search: {
  id: 'FG1'
}

return :{
  "name": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC",
  "title": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC",
  "id": "BAR1",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Global Businesses",
    "title": "Global Businesses",
    "id": "GB1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Commercial Banking",
      "title": "Commercial Banking",
      "id": "CB1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES",
        "title": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES",
        "id": "FG1",
        "children": [{}]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: This seems like a homework task, it's obvious you should write a recursive method to walk down the tree.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your first approach (code)

Answer (score 3):

You could use this function:

```js
function findChild(obj, condition) {
    if (Object.entries(condition).every( ([k,v]) => obj[k] === v )) {
        return obj;
    }
    for (const child of obj.children || []) {
        const found = findChild(child, condition);
        // If found, then add this node to the ancestors of the result
        if (found) return Object.assign({}, obj, { children: [found] });
    }
}
// Sample data
var input = { "children": [{ "name": "Home", "title": "Home", "id": "home1", "children": [] }, { "name": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC", "title": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC", "id": "BAR1", "children": [{ "name": "Global Businesses", "title": "Global Businesses", "id": "GB1", "children": [{ "name": "Commercial Banking", "title": "Commercial Banking", "id": "CB1", "children": [{ "name": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES", "title": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES", "id": "FG1", "children": [] }] }] }] }, { "name": "RISK MANAGEMENT", "title": "RISK MANAGEMENT", "id": "RM1", "children": [] } ]},
    search = { id: 'FG1' };

console.log(findChild(input, search));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can use this also for searching with *multiple* conditions, which must be true at the same time:

```
search = { "name": "Global Businesses", "title": "Global Businesses" };
```

... would give you the object that has the specified name and title.

#### Follow-up question

You asked in comments:

> Is there way to supply number to not remove children for given node in input. like,
>
> ```
> const donotRemoveChildNode = 2; 
> console.log(findChild(input, search, donotRemoveChildNode ));
> ```
>
> ...so it will not remove that specific node's children if it matches condition?
>
> Here, if we search for `{ id: 'FG1'}` and supply `donotRemoveChildNode = 2`, it would not remove the first level children for "Commercial banking".

I would say the `donotRemoveChildNode` would have to be 3, as there are three levels of `children` arrays in the ancestor-hierarchy of the "Commercial banking" node. A value of 0 would show the first level children of the top-most `children` property.

Here is how that extra argument would work -- I added some records to the data to illustrate the difference in the output:

```js
function findChild(obj, condition, removeChildNodesBefore = Infinity) {
    if (Object.entries(condition).every( ([k,v]) => obj[k] === v )) {
        return obj;
    }
    for (const child of obj.children || []) {
        let found = findChild(child, condition, removeChildNodesBefore - 1);
        if (found) {
            return Object.assign({}, obj, { 
                children: removeChildNodesBefore <= 0 
                    ? obj.children.map( sibling => 
                        sibling == child ? found 
                                         : Object.assign({}, sibling, {children: []}) 
                      )
                    : [found]
            });
        }
    }
}

var input = { "children": [{ "name": "Home", "title": "Home", "id": "home1", "children": [] }, { "name": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC", "title": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC", "id": "BAR1", "children": [{ "name": "Global Businesses", "title": "Global Businesses", "id": "GB1", "children": [{ "name": "test", "title": "test", "id": "xxx", "children": [{ "name": "testDeep", "title": "test", "id": "deep", "children": []}]}, { "name": "Commercial Banking", "title": "Commercial Banking", "id": "CB1", "children": [{ "name": "test", "title": "test", "id": "yyy", "children": []}, { "name": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES", "title": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES", "id": "FG1", "children": [] }] }] }] }, { "name": "RISK MANAGEMENT", "title": "RISK MANAGEMENT", "id": "RM1", "children": [] } ]},
    search = { id: 'FG1' }

console.log(findChild(input, search, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I need to have returned value from root till found object in hierarchy not just matching object.

Comment: So you want a tree that has siblings *removed* from the ancestors's children? I have updated my answer to do just that. Can you check?

Comment: thanks, exactly I was looking for, also I am not good with javascript but is there way to supply number to not remove children for given node in input. like, const donotRemoveChildNode = 2;  console.log(findChild(input, search, donotRemoveChildNode )); so it will not remove that specific node's children if it matches condition?, here if search for id : 'FG1' and supply donotRemoveChildNode  = 2 so it will not remove first level children for Commercial banking?

Comment: Do you mean *only* first level children, meaning that those children should have their own `children` property always equal to `[]`, even if they have children in the original input?

Comment: Anyway, I interpreted it like that, and added a section to my answer. Do you like it?

Comment: thanks for it, I did not get chance to look at it yesterday. i have updated js fiddle, I think it is still returning not correct result or may be I was not correct in writing.  jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L0nwunqd/2/, on jsfiddle I am searching for  `{
  guid: '677b7bc1-f429-4f2b-9347-463ac1aa89f7'
}` so it should return below result till hierarchy with children of  matching guid and it should also return children of nth element if nth element is part of hierarchy. I have added expected return in jsfiddle, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getBranch(branches, leaf_id)
{   
    var result_branch = null;

    branches.some(function(branch, idx) {
        if (branch.id == leaf_id) {
            result_branch = Object.assign({}, branch);
            result_branch.children.forEach(function(child, idx) {
                delete result_branch.children[idx].children;
            });

            return true;
        } else {
            let target_branch = getBranch(branch.children, leaf_id);

            if (target_branch) {
                result_branch = Object.assign({}, branch);
                delete result_branch.children
                result_branch.children = [target_branch];

                return true;    
            }
        }

        return false;
    });

    return result_branch;
}

console.log(getBranch(input.children, 'GB1'));
```

Comment: thanks @y-bond for function, i tried above function but even if I search for "GB1" it return everything from root till all child, I need to get from root till "GB1" with first level children in return.

Comment: ok, I've updated the function. If I get you right, it can work the way you want

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first loop the root children, and then create another function to see if the Id exists in any of it's children.

```js
var data = {
  "children": [{
      "name": "Home",
      "title": "Home",
      "id": "home1",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC",
      "title": "BUSINESS AND ROLE SPECIFIC",
      "id": "BAR1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Global Businesses",
        "title": "Global Businesses",
        "id": "GB1",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Commercial Banking",
          "title": "Commercial Banking",
          "id": "CB1",
          "children": [{
            "name": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES",
            "title": "FLAGSHIP PROGRAMMES",
            "id": "FG1",
            "children": []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "RISK MANAGEMENT",
      "title": "RISK MANAGEMENT",
      "id": "RM1",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
};

function hasId( id, data ) {
  if (data.id === id) return true;
  if (data.children) {
    for (const child of data.children) {
      if (hasId( id, child)) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function search( id, data ) {
  for (const child of data.children) {
    if (hasId(id, child)) return child;
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(search( "FG1", data ));
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it return all children from root I only want to select children who is part of hierarchy, so let say if I search for "FG1" then any of it parents's not all children should return except which are in path to reach "FG1"

Comment: @oypatel  `it return all children from root `  Not it doesn't.. Did you run the snippet above?

Comment: yes I did and it return all children from parent, I have created jsfiddle for same. can you plesae have quick look? https://jsfiddle.net/uz0a3LpL/1/

Comment: My snippet returns what your question say's it should, & your fiddle's source object is in a different format to your question.  IOW: Your question shows an object with a property called children, your fiddle is an array at it's root.. What is it?..

Comment: IOW: Press the button above that say's `Run code snippet`, examine the output.  You basically have 3 root nodes.. `home1`, `BAR1` & `RM1`, obviously `BAR1` is what we want, but can you see any reference to `home1` & `RM1` in the above output after running snippet.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Keith, I have updated jsfiddle now with same format as question. I want to have entire object hierarchy from root till object found. sorry for confusion

Comment: Your fiddle returns `LEADERSHIP` as the root, is this what you want?, but you have done -> `$("div#result").html(search( "1c80b174-54b0-469c-8522-64a606308561", data ));`  an object is not HTML,.. You could `JSON.stringify`  Here is your fiddle updated doing that -> https://jsfiddle.net/uz0a3LpL/2/